# Media player unable to add in new thread

Tags: java, android, xml, firebase, android-mediaplayer

Hello I am creating a media player app in which I retrieved the audio from Firebase database in a seperate fragment. But when I switches to that fragment it freezes for 5-10 seconds before start. It is too irritating. So I put the Media Player in a new thread, but I have use of media player outside the thread which causes error. THANKS...

Here is a sample of code =>

```
  new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mediaPlayer.setAudioAttributes(
                new AudioAttributes
                        .Builder()
                        .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                        .build());
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(audioUrl);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //set progress on seekbar
                seekBar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());

                //Handle post delay for 0.5 seconds
                handler.postDelayed(this, 50);
            }
        };

    }
}).start();

//Get duration of media player
int duration = mediaPlayer.getDuration();

//Convert milliseconds to minutes and seconds
String sDuration = convertFormat(duration);

//Set duration on text view
tv_seekbar_end.setText(sDuration);

play_audio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        play_audio.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        pause_audio.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }

        //Set max. on seek bar
        seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
        //Start handler
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 0);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below way, the below code is in kotlin but you can use this way in java

```
mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(mContext, myUri(uriAudio))
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        val audioAttributes: AudioAttributes =
                AudioAttributes.Builder()
                        .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
                        .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                        .build()
        mPlayer!!.setAudioAttributes(audioAttributes)
    } else {
        mPlayer!!.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)
    }

   
 if (mPlayer != null && !mPlayer!!.isPlaying) {
     mPlayer!!.start()
 }
```

please check this link may help you more
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68096841/4042384